# Update one column from another based on different cases in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have my table DDL and data like this:

```
create TABLE #TEMP_STATE
(
    ID [char](20) NOT NULL,
    [STATE] [char] (20) not null,
    TELEphonh [char](20)  NULL,
    TELEPHONW [char](14) NULL,
    dp [char](8) null,
    pp [char](8) null,
    Cid [char](16) null
)
```

[image]

I wanted to achieve following:

- Case 1 : When "PP" is Blank, check the "state" column, if "state" column has no "cell" or "C" or "M" then move the "State" column value to "PP"
- Case 2: When "State" column has a number concatenated with "Cell" and if "TELEPHONW" is blank, then move the "State" columns value to "TELEPHONW"
- Case 3: When "State" column has a number concatenated with "Cell" and if "TELEPHONH" is blank, then move the "State" columns value to "TELEPHONH"

**Note**:  `State` column can be blank after the data movement to other corresponding columns

So that, the output should look like this:

[image]

I'm trying the code like this:

```
update #TEMP_STATE
set TELEPHONH = CASE
   WHEN TELEPHONH like '' and TELEPHONW like '' and 
  PATINDEX('%cell%',SUBSTRING([STATE],NULLIF(PATINDEX( '%cell%', [STATE] 
),0),LEN([STATE])-1)) > 0
           THEN TELEPHONH = [STATE] ELSE [STATE] END,
   WHEN TELEPHONH like '' and TELEPHONW like '' and PATINDEX('%
 (C)%',SUBSTRING([STATE],NULLIF(PATINDEX( '%(C)%', [STATE] 
),0),LEN([STATE])-1)) > 0
           THEN TELEPHONH = [STATE] ELSE [STATE] END
FROM #TEMP_STATE
```

Hope I have explained this correctly.
However, I'm getting the syntax error? Can I not assign a column of one value to another inside the case?

Is there any other ways to achieve the desired result? Thanks.

Comment: What is the condition with DP? And are you looking for 1 update statement only or multiple updates are okay?

Comment: Try changing `Like '' ` to `IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the first 2 cases for you, but was confused on the 3rd one. You can apply your logic for the 3rd case then same way I did for the first 2. For the first 2 cases, I worked out my logic on columns `pp` and `TELEPHONW`, then I put that same logic into the `STATE` column.

The difference is when the logic is true in the `pp` and `TELEPHONW` columns, the value will be `STATE`. When the logic is true in the `STATE` column the value will be blank.

Hope this helps. Here it is on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f7d81/1/0)

```
UPDATE #TEMP_STATE
SET [STATE] = CASE WHEN (pp IS NULL OR pp = '') AND
                  (CHARINDEX('C',[STATE]) = 0 AND 
                   CHARINDEX('M',[STATE]) = 0) THEN ''
               WHEN (TELEPHONW IS NULL OR TELEPHONW = '') AND
                  CHARINDEX('CELL',[STATE]) > 0 AND
                  LEN([STATE]) > 4 THEN ''
               --Logic for 3rd condition here 
               ELSE [STATE] END,
     TELEPHONW = CASE WHEN (TELEPHONW IS NULL OR TELEPHONW = '') AND
                  CHARINDEX('CELL',[STATE]) > 0 AND
                  LEN([STATE]) > 4
                  THEN [STATE] ELSE TELEPHONW END,
      pp = CASE WHEN (pp IS NULL OR pp = '') AND
            (CHARINDEX('C',[STATE]) = 0 AND 
             CHARINDEX('M',[STATE]) = 0) 
             THEN [STATE] ELSE pp END
```

Comment: You can also ignore the 'cell' in the first CASE since it will be covered by the 'C' as well.

Comment: @ChesterLim, you are correct. I updated the code. Thanks!